# using a function that operates on 'this' in the jQuery.on( call

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, this

Consider the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JtN9W/4/

```
<div id= 'MyDiv'>screamer</div>

jQuery.fn.scream = function() {
   if(this.hasClass("scream")) {
      alert("scream");
   }
   else {
      alert("shhhh");
   }
}
$(function () {
   $('#MyDiv').scream();
   $('#MyDiv').on( "click", scream);
});
```

I am trying to bind the click event of a div to a JQuery function on the 'this' object. I know I can do this by changing the function and have it take the object as a variable, but I want to keep the function signature as is and have it internally work on the 'this' object. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fn` property is the prototype of the jQuery object, and that is used to add plugins to jQuery.

You *could* of course add a function to the prototype, and then use that as a callback for events, but that is not the intention and normally you would just use a regular function.

Note that an event handler is called with a reference to the element, not a jQuery object that contains the element, so you need to use `$(this)` to use a jQuery method on the element:

```
function scream() {
  if($(this).hasClass("scream")) {
    alert("scream");
  } else {
    alert("shhhh");
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('#MyDiv').on( "click", scream);
});
```

If you want to make a plugin, an implementation would normally look something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.scream = function() {
  return this.click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("scream")) {
      alert("scream");
    } else {
      alert("shhhh");
    }
  });
}

$(function () {
   $('#MyDiv').scream();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a `scream` function, but what you have is a `jQuery.fn.scream` function, as you've attached it to that namespace.

You can of course use that function as a reference in an event handler, but then the passed element in `this` will be a native DOM element, and must be wrapped in jQuery.

Why you would ever do it like this is beyond me, but here goes :

```
jQuery.fn.scream = function() {
   if( $(this).hasClass("scream") ) {
      alert("scream");
   }
   else {
      alert("shhhh");
   }
}
$(function () {
   $('#MyDiv').scream();
   $('#MyDiv').on( "click", jQuery.fn.scream);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JtN9W/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `this` to `$(this)`, and jQuery will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have following code

```
$('#MyDiv').on( "click", scream);
```

But there is no `scream` function defined in the current scope, instead, it's `jQuery.fn.scream`. Also, `hasClass` is a `jQuery` method and you need to use `$(this).hasClass("scream")` instead of `this.hasClass("scream")`, because `this` is not a `jQuery` object but `$(this)` is a `jQuery` object.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JtN9W/10/)